# How do I use conditional selection and groupby aggregation to produce a df with dummy variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dummy-variable

I have county-level data from the 2016 election and I would like to create dummy variables based on who won each county.

The df is in the following format:

```
FIPS  candidate  party  votepct
1001  Clinton     D      0.237
1001  Trump       R      0.727  
1001  Other      NaN     0.034
1003  Clinton     D      ...
1003  ...        ...     ...
```

I figured out a method that retrieves the winner in each county, but I'm trying to keep the rest of the columns. Here's what I have:

```
df.groupby('FIPS')['votepct'].max().reset_index()
```

Which yields:

```
   FIPS   votepct
0  1001   0.727
1  1003   0.765
2  1005   ...
```

I realize that I could potentially use a join, but that feels sloppy. What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Lets try find max value using transform and equate them to the values row wise and mask them.

```
df[df.groupby('FIPS')['votepct'].transform(lambda x:x.eq(x.max(),1))]
```

Comment: This approach is giving me a "length mismatch" error (new values have more elements than the expected axis). I tried resetting the index to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('FIPS')['votepct']
         .idxmax()]
```

Keep in mind that It is faster because you don't need use `eq`